# How to get the responsive resize proprties for a node - Adobe XD - plugins

Tags: plugins, adobe-xd

Trying to get the responsive resize properties of XD Nodes for an Adobe XD plugin i'm making. [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND47x.png)

is there a way to access them? or are they not yet supported in the Adobe XD plugin APIs?

I wasn't able to find anything about them in the [reference](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/scenegraph.html), here or on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any way to access this, yet. Similar to paragraph spacing, this feature is still too "new" in XD and therefore not yet included in the APIs. You could open a feature request for this in the official developer forum: https://forums.adobexdplatform.com/c/api-feedback/feature-requests